# Better cell wrapping for variable sized UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've created a UICollectionView and was wondering if there was a better way to create tight wrapping for individual cells in the view. Right now, if there is a larger cell in a column, the rest of the cells in that column become centered, like so:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve something like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it won't be using the default layout. You'll need to write a custom layout subclass.

Comment: You're right, I've subclassed the flow layout and am going to try adjusting the cell attributes through layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:. I'll be back to update if I make progress.